# Why does typedef affect function overloads?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, templates, typedef

I have two functions in a class (please comment on the issue and not the coding style):

```
template <typename T>
class myStringClass
{
public:
  ...

  typedef T* iterator;

  void erase(size_t pos, size_t n); // FUNC#1
  void erase(iterator first, iterator last); //FUNC#2
};
```

`FUNC#2` is erasing the range while `FUNC#1` simply calls `FUNC#2` after calculating the appropriate range. In `FUNC#1` instead of declaring `iterator` to calculate the range, I declared `T*` which is (should be?) essentially the same thing.

```
// SEGMENT#1 in function erase(size_t pos, size_t n)
T* begin = m_begin + pos;
T* end = begin + n;
erase(begin, end); // call FUNC#2
```

However, this does not compile. The compiler complains that it cannot convert T* (where T is a char) to size_t (i.e. trying to call `FUNC#1). But if I change the above code to:

```
// SEGMENT#2 in function erase(size_t pos, size_t n)
iterator begin = m_begin + pos;
iterator end = begin + n;
erase(begin, end); // call FUNC#2
```

Then the compiler is happy. I assumed that `typedef` was an alias and was not type-checked. So `SEGMENT#1 == SEGMENT#1` as far as the compiler is concerned? Why does one compile and the other doesn't?

---

**EDIT:** After testing Oli's code, I checked it against mine and I forgot to add `const` to the iterators in `SEGMENT#2`. Aside from the argument that adding const does not make sense in this case, why does that produce the error for `T*` and not `iterator`. Here is Oli's code slightly modified if you want to give it a try:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

template <typename T>
class myStringClass
{
private:
  T *m_begin;

public:

  typedef T* iterator;

  void erase(size_t pos, size_t n); // FUNC#1
  void erase(iterator first, iterator last); //FUNC#2
};


template <typename T>
void myStringClass<T>::erase(size_t pos, size_t n)
{
  const T* begin = m_begin + pos; // replace with iterator to compile
  const T* end = begin + n; // replace with iterator to compile
  erase(begin, end); // call the overload
}


template <typename T>
void myStringClass<T>::erase(const iterator first, const iterator last)
{
}

int main(void)
{
  myStringClass<char> x;
  x.erase(1,1);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add what compiler you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/9aHXs):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

template <typename T>
class myStringClass
{
private:
  T *m_begin;

public:

  typedef T* iterator;

  void erase(size_t pos, size_t n); // FUNC#1
  void erase(iterator first, iterator last); //FUNC#2
};


template <typename T>
void myStringClass<T>::erase(size_t pos, size_t n)
{
    T* begin = m_begin + pos;
    T* end = begin + n;
    erase(begin, end); // call the overload
}


template <typename T>
void myStringClass<T>::erase(iterator first, iterator last)
{
}


int main(void)
{
    myStringClass<char> x;
    x.erase(1,1);
}
```

Your problem must be elsewhere.

**UPDATE**

Now you've shown your real code...

The problem is you're trying to call a function that takes non-`const` pointers by passing it `const` pointers.  This isn't valid.

**UPDATE 2**

Now that you've shown your "real real" code...

The problem is that this:

```
typedef T *U;
const U x;
```

is not the same as:

```
const T *x;
```

it's actually the same as:

```
T *const x;
```

Comment: @Sjoerd: "0" is a bad choice, because it leads to an ambiguity.  But `x.erase(1,1)` is fine; see my updated question in a few seconds...

Comment: @Oli: (With regards to new edit) My apologies. I keep messing it up. If you change the function with iterators to take in `const`, that would make the code valid but it will fail to compile with `T*` but will compile with `iterator`. Btw, even with the invalid code as you mentioned, it still compiles (try it), which was surprising to me as well.

Comment: @Samaursa: Ok, I've updated again.  In future, please post your **exact**, **actual** code when you write your questions...

Comment: I will. Again, my apologies. I wanted to simplify it for the sake of the question but next time I will make an example like you did.

Comment: @Samaursa - When you don't know what a problem is, you can make the problem go away inadvertently by 'simplifying' it. If you knew what the crucial element was in causing a problem, you would likely already have solved it.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I agree although the `const` part was not what I was getting rid of in order to simply it. I re-wrote my code in the question text-box and forgot to put in the `const` keyword. The rest of the code is still simplified.

Comment: @Samaursa: The rule of thumb is: if you're asking a question about a compiler error, you must always copy-and-paste a complete code snippet that you've tried to compile.  Writing example code in the edit box is bound to lead to inaccuracies.

Answer (score 1):

It produces the error for `const T *` and not for `const iterator`. And the reason is that `const iterator` expands to `T * const`, not `const T *`.

```
extern int foo(int i);
extern int bar(int *i);

void baz()
{
   const int x = 5;
   int y = x;
   foo(x); // Perfectly fine
   foo(y); // Also perfectly fine
   bar(&x); // Not fine at all.
   bar(&y); // Perfectly fine.
}

void bouncy()
{
   typedef int my_t;
   typedef int *myptr_t;
   typedef const my_t const_my_t; // const (int) aka const int
   typedef const myptr_t const_myptr_t; // const (int *) aka int * const
}
```